# How to understand the flex C/C++ string literal regex?

Tags: c++, c, regex, flex-lexer, lex

I'm learning flex/bison for parsing technology. Book *flex & bison* shows such an flex example:

```
UCN (\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8})

{%
...
%}

%%

\"([^\"\\]|\\['"?\\abfnrtv]|\\[0-7]{1,3}|\\[Xx][0-9a-fA-F]+|{UCN})+\" { ... save token here }

%%
```

I have no idea about these parts inside of the regex:

1. does `[^\"\\]` means **do not match `\"` or `\\`**? if so, why need specify this **don't match**? since `\"` and `\\` seems not appear in the other group.
2. what does `\\[0-7]{1,3}` mean?
3. what does `\\[Xx][0-9a-fA-F]` mean?
4. does `UCN` mean utf-8?

Comment: Most questions about pattern syntax can easily be answered by consulting [the short chapter on patterns in flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That regular expression matches the following:

- A `"` character,
- Followed by any combination of one or more of the following:

  - `[^\"\\]` - Any character other than `"` or `\`
  - `\\['"?\\abfnrtv]` - A `\` followed by any of `'`, `"`, `?`, `\`, `a`, `b`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, or `v`.
  - `\\[0-7]{1,3}` - A `\` followed by one to three octal digits.
  - `\\[Xx][0-9a-fA-F]+` - A `\` followed by `X` or `x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits.
  - `{UCN}`, which expands to `(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8})` - Either of the following:

    - `\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}` - A `\` followed by `u` followed by four hexadecimal digits
    - `\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}` - A `\` followed by `U` followed by eight hexadecimal digits
- Followed by a closing `"` character

Note that this isn't actually a correct pattern for matching all C++ string literals because

- It doesn't match the empty string (`""`)
- Hex escape codes must begin with a lower-case `x`.  A better pattern for matching those would be `\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+`

For more info about what all of the C++ escape sequences mean, see [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

To answer your specific questions:

1. `\` denotes an escape sequence, which is handled by the other options, and an un-escaped `"` means the end of the string literal.  The generic "any character" match doesn't match either of those characters so that they can be matched by other parts of the expression.
2. Answered above: `\\[0-7]{1,3}` means a `\` followed by one to three octal digits.
3. Answered above: `\\[Xx][0-9a-fA-F]+` means a `\` followed by `X` or `x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits
4. `UCN` is short for Universal Character Name.  It denotes a Unicode character, but doesn't say anything about its encoding.

Comment: so all the *octal digits*, *hex digits*, *UCN* just presents an integer, which is a literal character ?

Comment: Yes, for example, the tokens `"\101"`, `"\x41"`, `"\u0041"`, `"\U00000041"`, and `"A"` all represent the same string.

Comment: Strictly, you can't use a UCN for Latin Capital Letter A — see C11 [Annex D](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#D) for example.  But if you were allowed, your mapping is correct.

Comment: It might be worth noting that C can prefix strings with `L`, `u8`, `u` and `U`; C++ has all those plus `R` (which can be prefixed by one of the other prefixes too) for 'raw string literals', and there are some fiendish requirements on them.  In particular, raw string literals can contain lots of things that are not permitted in ordinary string literals — e.g. `char32_t pqr[] = UR"RuR(close) are allowed")Ru inside a raw")")"string"!!)RuR";`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Annex D is irrelevant to string literals. Although normative, it's scope is delimited: "This clause lists the hexadecimal code values that are valid in universal character names ***in identifiers***." (Emphasis added.) The prohibition is in [6.4.4.4/8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p8): "characters ***not in the basic character set*** are representable by universal character names." (for string literals see 6.4.4.5/4). Also see 6.4.3/2, A UCN "shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0...". C++ doesn't have these restrictions.

Comment: @rici — You're right.  I'm going to put that down to fuzzy-brains due to a streaming cold.

Answer (score 1):

1. `[^...]` means match any single element that is *not* ...
2. `\\[0-7]{1,3}` means to match a \ followed by one to three characters from the set 0-7 (the matches need not be the same character, for instance "\123" is matched)
3. `\\[Xx][0-9a-fA-F]` means to match a \ followed by either an x or X followed by a character from the set 0-9a-fA-F
4. UCN is an example of a lex custom definition, such definitions allow for a regex pattern to be repeated later without needing to copy the entire pattern; instead it can just be enclosed in curly braces {UCN}

I suggest you find material about regexes if the first three are really that much of a confusion, the flex manual can tell you about definitions: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/Definitions-Section.html#Definitions-Section